# jQuery keeps getting value of wrong radio button if checked by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, default

Radio buttons, the first one is checked by default:

```
  <div class="shipping">
    <div class="title">Select shipping method</div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="courier-dpd" checked="checked">Courier DPD</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="personal">Personal pick up</label>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
```

Js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.shipping button', function() {
  let val = $('.shipping').find('input[name="shipping"]:checked').val()
  console.log(val);
}
```

Even if I manually switch the radio buttons and select the second one, jQuery keeps getting the value of the first radio button, independently on user selection.

Why is that? I can't find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:** Added JS code from updated question. It seems to work here.

**Edit:** Added submit button to demonstrate submit action.

---

Well, are you calling `console.log` after changing the value? I created a snippet below and it works fine.

```js
$(function() {
  let val = $('.shipping').find('input[name="shipping"]:checked').val()
  console.log(val);

  /*$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    let val = $('.shipping').find('input[name="shipping"]:checked').val()
    console.log(val);
  })*/

  $(document).on('click', '.shipping button', function() {
    let val = $('.shipping').find('input[name="shipping"]:checked').val()
    console.log(val);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shipping">
  <div class="title">Select shipping method</div>
  <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="courier-dpd" checked="checked">Courier DPD</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="personal">Personal pick up</label>
  <button>Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this definitely does not work in my project for some reason

Comment: Using the exact same code I have posted does not work?

Comment: I've update my question so you can see how I am handling the event

Comment: Where is the button?

Comment: Right below the inputs, added to my question

Comment: I found a mistake, I was reading the values on 'form show' event, not on submit event

Comment: Oh well, we all make mistakes like that. Good you found it.